# ERROR: The ejabberd node 'ejabberd@localhost' is already running in Windows 8

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

When I am trying to start Ejabberd service then I got this error. I have tried in Windows 8

Answer (score 0):

are sure your service is not started!! you can check telnet server_ip 5222

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and I solved it by running the task manager, ending all 'ejabberd related tasks' then running ejabberd as an Administration from the shortcut created on the desktop during installation.
Hope it works for you.

Ps: I am using Windows 8.1 too.